# How to compute the coefficients of the general form of a line $ax + by + d = 0$ in a way that helps to find the plane equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I have a bunch of points $(x,y,z)$. I want to compute the best fit line equation going through those points in 2D (I want the line in 2D so I just ignored the z axis for the line). I have done that using the line equation in the form $y=mx+n$ and the least squares:

I have many points, thus many equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & 1 \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
x_n & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\
n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To simplify, the y vector is "$B$", $x_1$ is "$A$" and coefficients "$X$": $B=AX \Leftrightarrow X=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$

Using $y=mx+n$ with the calculated coefficients, I now calculated the plane going through the 3D points. I needed 3 points so I calculated 2 points in the line by arbitrarily choosing a "$x$" value to find "$y$" and took a random other point in my data set that doesn't belong to the line. I now have 3 points $A$,$B$ and $C$, I do the cross product of $(A-B*A-B)$ and get $a,b,c$ from the plane equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$, then I can get d using those values and a point.

$$$$

I now have a line equation $y=mx+n$ and plane equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$

However I would like to calculate the best fit line equation using this line equation form: $ax+by+d=0$ in a way that would allow me to extend/slightly adjust to also calculate the plane equation.

I know that with 2 known points and by using the point-slope form of the line equation $${y-y_B}={\textstyle y_B-y_A\over \textstyle \strut x_B-x_A}(x-x_B)$$

I can then have this: $$(y_A-y_B)x-(x_A-x_B)y+x_Ay_B-x_By_A=0$$

Meaning I'd have:
$$a=(y_A-y_B)\\b=(x_A-x_B)\\d=(x_Ay_B-x_By_A)$$

However that's for 2 points only, not a best fit line.

I also know that with this general form $ax+by+d=0$ I get $y=-{\textstyle a\over \textstyle \strut b}x-{\textstyle d\over \textstyle \strut b}$ but I don't know how to get $b$ and how to use that in a way that would allow me to "extend/adjust" to find the plane equation.

Comment: To find better fitting line one need to define what is "better". For example one can take goal function as $\sum_i(y_i-mx_i-n)^2$ and minimize it over $m$ and $n$. This is standard linear regression problem and there are ready formulae for it. Equation $ax+by+d=0$ is not unique, because it describes the same line as $2ax+2by+2d=0$. If $m$ is finite in $y=mx+n$, one can take any non-negative value of $b$.

Comment: To find $c$ one can use the same approach. Let best fit in 2D is $y=mx+n$, then one can take $a=m$, $b=-1$, $d=n$. Then we search for $c$ in equation $mx-y+cz+n=0$. Then we can take goal function in form $\sum_i (mx_i-y_i+cz_i+n)^2$ and minimize it over $c$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thx, I had in my mind that I just couldn't take the coefficients of the line equation from this form $y=ax+b$ because in this form $ax + by + c = 0$ "y" equals to $y=(-a/b)x-(c/b)$